# Set-ItemProperty creates a duplicate registry key

Tags: powershell, registry

I am trying to activate Long path names in Windows 10 1903.

When I run as administrator in Windows PowerShell :

```
Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -value '1'
```

I see that a new registry key has been created, instead of overwriting existing one.

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is **no reason to assume a *bug*** here - your command should work as intended, but it does the wrong thing (see below).
- The **symptom you show - duplicate value names in a registry key - are inconsistent with the command in your question**.

  - **The underlying native registry APIs do *not* allow creating values with duplicate names in a given registry key**; if they did - which would be a serious bug - the problem would lie there, not in PowerShell.
  - If the registry editor really shows two values whose names *appear to be* identical, the only plausible explanation is that they contain invisible characters that makes them different.

---

As for **what you tried**:

The system-known `LongPathsEnabled` registry value of key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` 
is a 64-bit *integer*, of registry type `REG_DWORD`, equivalent to a `[uint32]` instance in .NET / PowerShell.

**By using `-Value '1'` in your `Set-ItemProperty` call, you're letting it *infer* what registry type to write the value as, and that is `REG_SZ`**, i.e. a literal string:

- However, if the target value *already exists*, and is of - the correct - type `REG_DWORD`, PowerShell will *convert* the string for you.
- By contrast, **if no such value exists yet, you'll - incorrectly - create a `REG_SZ` value**.

---

Your [own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58328196/45375) now uses `-Value 1`, which makes the `1` implicitly an `[int]` (`System.Int32`), in which case PowerShell *correctly* infers `REG_DWORD`.

**However - both for readability and robustness - consider using the `-Type` parameter to explicitly indicate the type of registry value you're planning to create** (command spread across multiple lines for readability - note the `` ` `` chars. at the end of the interior lines, which must be the very last char. on their respective lines):

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' `
  -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' `
  -Value 1 `
  -Type DWord
```

The `-Type` argument is of type [`Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind), which, when you create or set a value, must be one of the following values (shown here mapped to their `REG_*` values):

```
String        # REG_SZ
ExpandString  # REG_EXPAND_SZ
Binary        # REG_BINARY
DWord         # REG_DWORD
MultiString   # REG_MULTI_SZ
QWord         # REG_QWORD
```

The full list of *native* `REG_*` types can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Unquoted the value.

```
Set-ItemProperty -path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -value 1
```

Now I can play with WSL.

Enjoy.

Comment: I'm curious how you managed to create duplicate values, because I would expect the underlying native registry APIs to prevent that - are there hidden characters in your seemingly duplicate value? Also, the command in your question wouldn't have created a `REG_DWORD` value, it would have created a `REG_SZ` value - as would the commands in your answer (though updating an existing `REG_DWORD` value would automatically convert string `'1'` to a `REG_DWORD`). Do you have a reproducible case for the suspected bug?

Comment: Thanks. I went over and figured it out. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Push-Location
Set-Location 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem'
Set-ItemProperty -path .\ -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -value 1 -Type DWord -Force
Pop-Location
```

Comment: I changed my answer. I cannot use multi-lines code as I am writing a tutorial for beginners. I'm afraid they'll leave if they see too much code.
Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: Didn't focused on String/DWord. Sorry for that. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the data-type issue - but your solution still wouldn't make a difference - it's just more verbose.